# jQuery - bootstrap datepicker - how to reload/destroy?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I use bootstrap datepicker (here is URL: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) on my website. I load many elements dynamicly using AJAX (and forms too) so on first initialize AJAX I just add this code in AJAX complete function:

```
$(function(){
        // disabling dates
            var nowTemp = new Date();
            var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), (nowTemp.getDate()+1), 0, 0, 0, 0);

            var checkin = $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                onRender: function(date) {
                    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                }
            }).data('datepicker');
        });
```

but when AJAX is initialize second and once again, in console I got:

`TypeError: date is undefined` in file which you can download from: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ The file name is: js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

So I tried also on second and once again initialize, destroy this datepicker in that way:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('remove');
```

and in that way:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
```

and then load function that load datepicker (look, first code in my post)
but in console I got: `TypeError: data[option] is not a function`

Here is my function which I use in every initialize AJAX:

```
function form_refreshing()
    {
        $('input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio],input[type=file]').uniform();
        $('select').select2();

        if ( parseInt($('#new_page_loaded').val()) !== 0 ) // checking which time AJAX is initialize, if more than once - remove/destroy datepicker fisrt, and then load it again
        {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker('remove'); // I tried also with destroy and in console I got the same error
        }
        $(function(){
        // disabling dates
            var nowTemp = new Date();
            var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), (nowTemp.getDate()+1), 0, 0, 0, 0);

            var checkin = $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                onRender: function(date) {
                    return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
                }
            }).data('datepicker');
        });

        return;
    }
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue.  I had the date/time picker in a modal, and I needed to insure the minDate was "NOW" at all times.

My solution was:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate());
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker("minDate", date);
```

So you can see, this is how I load up the date picker in the first place:

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate());

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    inline: true,
    sideBySide: true,
    minDate: date
});
```

All I had to do was reset that minDate and it worked.

Hope this helps you?